# Flutter Chart with event marker on x-axis

Tags: flutter, flutter-charts

A total noob to flutter, I have a line chart and want to mark important events on the x-axis. The chart tracks heart beat rate. x-axis is the time. I want to mark events like workout start, etc which will be just one symbol. Also things like sleep will be marked with a continuous long marker spanning the entire duration.
Unable to find any solution for the same in the flutter eco-system. Can any one help me out here

Comment: can you include sample code that you've tried so far

Comment: I don't have sample code @Md.YeasinSheikh I was trying to see if I can do something with the existing chart libs. They don't provide any support for the same. Are there any libs that support this ?

Comment: you can checkout fl_chart from pub.dev, this may help. also you can use search there

Comment: @Md.YeasinSheikh checked fl_charts. I guess I have to redraw the x-axis with the special symbol. Was not very happy with  solution. Checking [Community Charts Example](https://juliansteenbakker.github.io/community_charts/flutter/example/time_series_charts/symbol_annotation). Still missing a couple of required features